# Getting milliseconds in AutoHotkey

Tags: timestamp, autohotkey, milliseconds

How do I add milliseconds to the AHK script below?  I have been researching and can't find a way - or better yet, don't understand some of the solutions posted in SO... nor do I know enough about any kind of programming. Can you help?

How would I get milliseconds in this?

```
runwait, net time /setsntp:"us.pool.ntp.org",,hide
run, w32tm /resync,,hide

^Space::

FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, hh:mm:ss tt{Enter}{Down}

sendInput %CurrentDateTime%

return
```

Comment: I ma not sure what is the purpose of the `{Enter}{Down}` in your code, ignoring that part I added an answer below.

Comment: i will try it when i get home.  thank you!  i use the timestamp to run dog sled races... so when mushers come in, and i hit crtl+spacebar, a timestamp is entered and the cursor goes down to the next cell in google sheets.  that way, if two or three mushers are coming, i can get all three stamps without having to move to another cell... makes sense?

Comment: Sure, makes sense when you see that the next command is `Sendinput` :) At first I was just looking only at the `FormatTime` command, and there it was a bit out of place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add the milliseconds you can use the [A_Msec](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#MSec) built-in variable.

Change this line:

```
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, hh:mm:ss tt{Enter}{Down}
```

to

```
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, hh:mm:ss:%A_msec% tt
```